# obtaining comments for each post

Tags: php, html, mysql, comments

hi I have to create a system of comments within various trhead I performed before and all the while the trhead 'while inside the comment and it works but is really slow and with a large number of threads often gives me timeout error how can I fix the problem?

```
function commenti($id) {

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE numid='$id' ORDER BY id ASC";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
if($result2->num_rows >0)
 {

  while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
$idt2 =  $row2['id'];

$testot2 = $row2['testo'];

return $testot2;
  }
 } else {
echo "No comment";

}
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 where visualizza='1' ORDER BY id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if($result->num_rows >0)
 {

  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
$id =  $row['id'];

$titolo = $row['titolo'];




$testo = commenti($id);
echo "$titolo $testo <br>";
}
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: How many comments are on a post or article? I dont see how it would be slow unless your server doesnt have enough resources but if that was the case it would be ancient.

Comment: although he did not comment on post 40 is slow

Comment: Database calls for anything other than a heap of data isnt the problem. A join is this instance would preform at the same pace. I recommend using pagination of some sort. You could even just include a next button and a previous button to cycle through the posts. Ill post a quick example of how to do it shortly if no one else beats me to it.

Comment: Now try putting 10 posts and 10 comments for post

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are trying to pull a ton of records. The best way to approach this is to add pagination and only load ~10-20 comments per page. *depending on your server*

Update:

@OP Basically on first load of the page you load ~10 comments, once they click view more then you load in the next few using ajax. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment to the OP. It isn't an answer.

Comment: facebook for example how do you handle all the posts and comments?

Answer (score 0):

I thought to use the join but if there are more duplicates also post comments

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 left JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.numid where visualizza='1' ORDER BY id DESC";
```